# Getting NullPointerException for different step definition files with cucumber and selenium

Tags: automated-testing, java, cucumber, selenium3

```
Browser utility:

package com.gmsr.utility;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class BrowserUtility {
    
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebDriver openBrowser(WebDriver driver, String browserName, String url) throws InterruptedException {
        
        if(browserName.equals("chrome")) {
            
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(url);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            return driver;
            
            
            
            
        }else
        if(browserName.equals("IE")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);
        Thread.sleep(5000); 
        return driver;
        
        
    }else
    if(browserName.equals("Firefox")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);
        Thread.sleep(5000); 
        return driver;
    }
        return driver;

}
public static WebDriver getDriver() throws Exception {
    if(driver == null) {

        
        PropertiesFileReader obj=new PropertiesFileReader(); 
        Properties properties=obj.getproperty();
        openBrowser(properties.getProperty("browserName"), properties.getProperty("URL"));
    }else {
        return driver;
    }
    return driver;
}
    

}
```

**Login page :**

```
package com.gmsr.pageobjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class LoginPage {
    
    WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        
    }
    
    @FindBy(how=How.ID,using="ignin-username")
    public WebElement usernametexbox;
    
    @FindBy(how=How.ID,using="signin-password")
    public WebElement passwordtextbox;
    
    @FindBy(how=How.ID,using="signin-submit")
    public WebElement signin;
    
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//button[@class='-primary']")
    public WebElement acceptbutton;
    
   public void enter_username(String username) {
        
    usernametexbox.clear();
    usernametexbox.sendKeys(username);
    usernametexbox.getText();
    }
    
    public void enter_password(String password) {
        
        passwordtextbox.clear();
        passwordtextbox.sendKeys(password);
    }
    
    public void clickToSigninbutton() {
        signin.click();
    }
    
    public void clickToAcceptbutton() {
        
        
    acceptbutton.click();
        
    }
    
public void fill_LoginDetails() {
    
    enter_username("gggg");
    enter_password("fffff");
        
        
        
    }
    

}
```

**Logout page:**

```
package com.gmsr.pageobjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.gmsr.stepdef.StepDefinition;

public class LogoutPage  {
    
    WebDriver driver;

    public LogoutPage() {
        
    
        
    }
    
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@class='icon-caret']")
    public WebElement chevron;
    
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//a[@class='logout-link']")
    public WebElement logoutlink;
    
    public void clickTochevron() {
        chevron.click();
    }
    
    public void clickToLogoutLink() {
        
        
        logoutlink.click();
        
    }
    
    }
```

**Login step definition:**

```
package com.gmsr.stepdef;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import com.gmsr.pageobjects.LoginPage;
import com.gmsr.utility.BrowserUtility;
import com.gmsr.utility.PropertiesFileReader;

import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;

public class StepDefinition {
    
/*    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return getDriver();
          
      } */
    
     
       public static WebDriver driver;
    
        private LoginPage loginpage;
     
     
    
    Properties properties=new Properties();
    PropertiesFileReader obj=new PropertiesFileReader(); 
    
    
    @Given("^Open browser and enter url$")
    public void open_browser_and_enter_url() throws Throwable {
                   
           
    
     Properties properties=obj.getproperty();
     driver=BrowserUtility.openBrowser(driver, properties.getProperty("browserName"), properties.getProperty("URL"));
        
    }
    
    @Then("^Enter username and password$")
    public void enter_username_and_password() throws Throwable {
        
    LoginPage loginpage=new LoginPage(driver);
    loginpage.fill_LoginDetails();
        
            }
    
    @Then("^click on sign in button$")
    public void click_on_sign_in_button() throws Throwable {
        
        new LoginPage(driver).clickToSigninbutton();
        System.out.println("Sign-In successfully");
        
    }

    
    @Then("^Terms and conditions page open and click on Accept button$")
    public void terms_and_conditions_page_open_and_click_on_Accept_button() throws Throwable {
        
        
        new LoginPage(driver).clickToAcceptbutton();
    }

    

}
```

**Logout stepdef:**

```
package com.gmsr.stepdef;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import com.gmsr.pageobjects.LoginPage;
import com.gmsr.pageobjects.LogoutPage;
import com.gmsr.utility.BrowserUtility;
import com.gmsr.utility.PropertiesFileReader;

import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;



public class Logoutstepdef{
    
public static WebDriver driver;
    //  private StepDefinition stepdefinition;
public void loadDriver() throws Exception {
     this.driver = BrowserUtility.getDriver();
}



public LogoutPage logoutpage = new LogoutPage();
    //  PropertiesFileReader obj=new PropertiesFileReader();

 
@Given("^Chevron near username$")
public void chevron_near_username() throws Throwable {

loadDriver();
 
    //  Properties properties=obj.getproperty();        
   /*driver=    BrowserUtility.openBrowser(driver, properties.getProperty("browser.Name"), 
        properties.getProperty("URL"));*/
   //   stepdefinition.open_browser_and_enter_url();
   //   stepdefinition.click_on_sign_in_button();
 // stepdefinition.terms_and_conditions_page_open_and_click_on_Accept_button();


//  LogoutPage logoutpage=new LogoutPage();
    
 
   logoutpage.clickTochevron(driver);
}

@And("^click on chevron and it should get expands$")
public void click_on_chevron_and_it_should_get_expands() throws Throwable {
    
    System.out.println("when user click on checvron it should further expands a window");
    
}

@And("^click on Logout link$")
public void click_on_Logout_link() throws Throwable {
    
//  logoutpage.clickToLogoutLink();
    new LogoutPage().clickToLogoutLink(driver);
    
}

}
```

Login step definition is working fine. But getting `nullpointerexception` for Logout step definition.

Pls help to resolve this - I have updated my code and now getting null value for element `chevron` and `logoutlink` available in `logoutpage`

Comment: According to your code structure you have not made the instance of **BrowserUtility** , so i will suggest you that just add this line in your **Logout** class    ``` Properties properties=obj.getproperty();```
    ~~~ driver=BrowserUtility.openBrowser(driver, properties.getProperty("browserName"), properties.getProperty("URL")); ~~~

Comment: No it doesnt work still getting the null pointer exception

Comment: Yes, you can not create driver instance multiple time for one test, you need to make a base class then inherit that base class in your test class, it will work .

Comment: we cannot inherit any class into step definition file, cucumber doesnt allow to do so, do you have any alternative solution for the same I am stuck

Comment: why are you using this ```public LogoutPage() {
        this.driver=StepDefinition.driver;


    }``` if this is page factory class?

Comment: I have changed my code and added a piece of code public static WebDriver getDriver() throws Exception {
  if(driver == null) {

      
      PropertiesFileReader obj=new PropertiesFileReader(); 
   Properties properties=obj.getproperty();
   openBrowser(properties.getProperty("browserName"), properties.getProperty("URL"));
  }else {
   return driver;
  }
  return driver;
 }
 to BrowserUtility class

Comment: Why? is this the solution, i'm not able to understand what you want to do

Comment: I will suggest you that just change your structure, you have declare the chrome driver instance in all ```If``` conditions, in login you are using PageFactory but in Logout not.

Comment: that is not an issue I have not provided any exe files path for other browser and this is not impacting my code and for logout I have used pagefactory only

Comment: ok it's not impacting your code, nut if your structure will be good then it will be easy for you to track you issue.

Comment: Your description of your nullpointerexception is too vague.  it's almost certainly your incorrect usage of the driver, but a more detailed error message would help a lot, like the stack trace, and showing us exactly which line is getting the exception.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.gmsr.pageobjects.LogoutPage.clickTochevron(LogoutPage.java:48)
 at com.gmsr.stepdef.Logoutstepdef.chevron_near_username(Logoutstepdef.java:51)
 at ✽.Given Chevron near username(logoutpage.feature:5)  This is getting on console

Comment: I am getting null value for WebElement chevron here package com.gmsr.pageobjects;--Previously it was null for driver